# Christian answers as Spam

Tags: discussion, spam

This morning, I saw (and subsequently down voted) answers by a new user [Dr. Cortes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/13141/dr-cortes), which appeared to be trying to answer the questions with Christian messianic responses (eg. about Yoshke and Paul). These answers are clearly off-topic and arguably spam. Should such answers be tagged as such to expedite their removal (rather than waiting for sufficient down votes)?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor/58035#58035) is the official guidance on the use of the Spam flag, linked [in our FAQ](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). I think that considering answers like those you've described as "unsolicited advertisements" for another religion is a bit of a stretch; I'm not sure whether it's an advisable stretch to make or not.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/promotion (cc @IsaacMoses )

Answer (score 11):

I have deleted some Christian (and other) answers as spam when they evangelize.  We've gotten some pretty blatant preaching at times -- from Christians, Muslims, and the occasional super-emphatic atheist.  (Sometimes these posts are offensive instead of, or in addition to, being spam, by the way.)

Merely answering from or assuming a Christian (etc) perspective isn't enough for me to consider it spam.  I think the two examples you pointed out are below that bar; they're misguided, they're non-answers, and they should definitely have been deleted, but they're not spam.  Spam/offensive deletions impose penalties, which we shouldn't apply to the merely misguided.

I'm sorry I can't give a better definition, beyond this and what's in the help center on [flags](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) and [promotion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).  Each case has to be evaluated.

If you don't have the delete-answers privilege, or if the post doesn't yet qualify due to voting, you can bring it up in chat to get more eyes on it and/or flag as not an answer (which sends it to the review queue).  And downvote, which you already did (thanks).

I can't speak for the other mods, but while we generally let the community handle NAA flags if it can, I do look at them when I see them.  If I see something blatant I nuke it; why leave it on the site and ask more people to do work?  So flagging does get moderator attention.

Answer (score 4):

I feel all answers not answering from a Jewish perspective should not be flagged as spam or offensive for @Monica's reasons, but they should be flagged as not an answer. If the answer doesn't answer the question, which implicitly asks for a Jewish perspective, that is the correct flag reason.